# How to get Elastic IP address of servers behind Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a couple of servers behind an amazon load balancer and I need to find out their elastic IP addresses so I can SSH into them.  (I'm on a different computer than normal and have left my amazon hardware authenticator back home in a different country so I can't just log into the AWS console).

Is there any way of obtaining these two addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a long shot, since you're not on your usual computer, but do you have the command line tools installed?

```
aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name <ELB name>
```

Returns a list of instances connected to the ELB.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances <instance id>
```

Returns among other things the IP address of the instance. If you have your Access Key and Secret Key you can set up the command line tools and skip the AWS console.

EC2 tools: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html

ELB tools: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTheCommandLineTools.html

UPDATE: As of this edit the ELB Command Line tools have been replaced in favour of AWS CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html

[Documentation for AWS CLI with ELB commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/index.html)

Comment: Whether this helps the OP or not this is clever! +1

Comment: Great answer!  Before you responded I was able to get someone onto one of my PCs back home and send me my .bash_history file and I got the IP addresses from there.  Thanks again.